# How to read files with spaces using Expo FileSystem

Tags: react-native

I can't find anything in the documentation but it seems that Expo's FileSystem has trouble reading files with spaces in their names.

Let's say I have two files, `const file_a = 'File_A.txt'` and `const file_b = 'File B.txt'`, (note the latter has a space in the name); both have been added to my app's cacheDirectory using

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as DocumentPicker from 'expo-document-picker';
const file = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync();
```

I then run:

```
const targetPath = FileSystem.cacheDirectory;

console.log(await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(targetPath + file_a));
console.log(await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(targetPath + file_b));
```

The output for file_a gives the appropriate information about the file. For file_b I get an error: `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: File 'file:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../File%20B.txt -- file:///' isn't readable.]`

I also get errors when trying to use the `FileSystem.moveAsync()` function on file_b, telling me I didn't provide a 'from' field (probably because the from field has spaces in it)

If I rename file_b to File_B.txt then reimport it, the `getInfoAsync()` function returns the correct information.

**Is there a way to get FileSystem to work with files with spaces in their names or is there a way to simply rename the files? Of course I can't rename them via `moveAsync()` as the move function doesn't work, as described above.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I do `.replace(/ /g, "%20")` on the file names before using `FileSystem.getInfoAsync()`, it works.

(Edit: this replaces all spaces in the file name with '%20', which is a an encoded 'space' string used for URLs and the like.)